# Is it better to create a Many to Many relationship table or Single column in the first table to save ref records ids as CSV

Tags: relational-database, relationship, rdbms

Is it always better for small Many to Many relationship table while we just need to save single id of reference table in a new table as usual like:

```
Attributes
|Id | Name          |
---------------------
| 1 | Attribute 1   |
| 2 | Attribute 2   |
Items
|Id | Name      |
-----------------
| 1 | Item 1    |
| 2 | Item 2    |
ItemAttributes
|ItemId | AttributeId |
-----------------------
| 1     | 1           |
| 1     | 2           |
| 2     | 2           |
```

or Single column in the first table, to save referenced table records ids as CSV like:

```
Attributes
|Id | Name          |
---------------------
| 1 | Attribute 1   |
| 2 | Attribute 2   |
Items
|Id | Name      | AttributesIds  |
----------------------------------
| 1 | Item 1    | 1, 2           |
| 2 | Item 2    | 1              |
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of using the DBMS's built-in functionality for joining tables, indexing columns, FK constraints, cascading updates, etc., the first method is always better.